# Fastest way to lookup with pattern

Tags: c#, data-structures

Imagine I have a list of several-hundred unique names, e.g.

```
["john", "maria", "joseph", "richard", "samantha", "isaac", ...]
```

What's the best way I can store these to provide a fast lookup-time by matching against a pattern?

I only need to match "masks", can't think of a better word for it.

Basically, I get in letters and their positions, `____a__` (where `_` represents an unknown letter.) Then I need to find all values in the data structure that match that mask, e.g. in this case it would return "richard", but it should also be possible to get multiple "returned" values.

Comment: The fastest way is to use a hash.  A dictionary has a built in hash on the keys so you can either create you own hash or use a dictionary.

Comment: @jdweng does that retain order as well though?

Comment: Which kind of patterns do you want to match? Prefix queries are rather easy to index, for example, but if you want to support generic patterns I fear that you cannot do better than O(n) (i.e. linear scan)

Comment: A hash doesn't change order.  It just creates a binary tree to locate an item.  Binary lookup requires average lookup of Log2(N) while straight lookup requires average N/2.  There is also a SortedDictionary which stores key in sorted order.

Comment: Ok guys, the only patterns I need to match are like "masks", e.g. `....a..`. Basically, I know some letters and their positions, and need to find all values from the list that match it.

Comment: im not trying to be negative but you cant go faster than `O(n)` i.e just use list and that's the fastest way you can do.

Comment: if you sort your list first then there maybe some ways to improve search performance using binary search.

Comment: I note you say you want the "fastest" but then push back on the fast solution for taking up a lot of memory. You don't actually want *fastest*; no one does. You want *fast enough given a certain budget*, where that budget includes your time spent programming, the hardware you have, the memory it has, and so on. So: what is your *real* performance goal? Always start with a goal; if you don't, then you don't know when you've met it and can worry about something else.

Comment: @EricLippert you are wrong. I just want the fastest algorithm. I don't care about memory, I was just wondering.

Comment: Then start composing a team to build specialty hardware. You should be able to solve this problem faster than anyone else in the world with specialty supercomputers for under a billion dollars!

Comment: Now, if you want the fastest *algorithm*, that's easy. You have the list of names. There are finitely many queries. So simply construct an algorithm as slow as you like, run *all* the queries, record the results in a fast lookup table, and you're done. The resulting algorithm will be the fastest because all it does is map from the question to the precomputed answer. Combine that with custom hardware and you'll have a really fast solution to this problem.

Comment: @EricLippert wait, that's sounds viable. There would be about 10^20 possibilities, so a couple gigabytes in memory? How would I actually implement that in C# though?

Comment: 10^20 is considerably more than "a couple gigabytes". A gigabyte is 10^9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a lot of work for "hundreds" of names. Doing a linear search on a list of hundreds of names will be very fast. Now, if you're talking hundreds of thousands or millions ...

In any case, you can speed this up using a dictionary. You can pre-process the data into a dictionary whose keys are a combination of character and position, and values are the words that contain that character at that position. For example, if you were to index "john" and "joseph", you would have:

```
{'j',0},{"john","jospeh"}
{'o',1},{"john","joseph"}
{'h',2},{"john"}
{'n',3},{"john}
{'s',2},{"joseph"}
{'e',3},{"joseph"}
{'p',4},{"joseph"}
{'h',5},{"joseph"}
```

Now let's say you're given the mask "jo...." (the dots are "don't care"). You'd turn that into two keys:

```
{'j',0}
{'o',1}
```

You query the dictionary for the list of words that has 'j' at index 0. Then you query the dictionary for the list of words that has 'o' at index 1. Then you intersect the lists to get your result.

It's a simple inverted index, but on character rather than on word.

The lists themselves will cost you a total of O(m * n) space, where m is the total number of words and n is the average word length in characters. At maximum, the number of dictionary entries will be 26*max_word_length. In practice, it will probably be much less.

If you make the values a `HashSet<string>` rather than `List<string>`, intersection will go much faster. It'll increase your memory footprint, though.

That should be faster than linear search if your masks contain only a few characters. The longer the mask, the more lists you'll have to intersect.

For the dictionary key, I'd recommend:

```
public struct Key
{
    public char KeyChar;
    public int Pos;
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)KeyChar + Pos << 16;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!obj is Key) return false;
        var other = (Key)obj;
        return KeyChar == other.KeyChar && Pos == other.Pos;
    }
}
```

So your dictionary would be `Dictionary<Key, HashSet<string>>`.

Comment: So store them in a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, HashSet<string>>`?

Comment: @minseong: I wouldn't recommend using a `Tuple`. See my update for what I would recommend for a key.

Answer (score 1):

If the longest word has m letters, then you can keep m lists l[1], ..., l[m] such that the words in each list l[i] are sorted lexicographically starting from the i-th letter in every word (shorter words will not appear in that list). Then, if your query is `...ac.`, just perform a binary search in list l[4].

This will cost you O(mn) in memory and takes O(m n log n) time to build, but will give you O(log n) query time, which is the fastest you can get.

**EDIT**
Good news, I have recently stumbled upon [range trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), that would allow you to perform this kind of queries somewhat efficiently, namely in O(log^m(n)+k) time, and requiring O(n log^(d-1)(n)) space.

They are not straightforward to implement, in the sense that you need to build a binary search tree sorting the words by the first letter, then build a binary search tree for every internal node which stores the words in the subtree of that node sorted by the second letter, and so on.

On the other hand, this would allow you to perform a wider range of queries, namely you can look for contiguous intervals of letters, i.e. a pattern like `..[a-c].[b-f].`

Comment: This is going to use up a lot of memory though right?

Comment: @minseong yes, but it's still affordable in most cases. For example, if you have 250k words of 50 letters each, it will take around (50*250000) bytes, (i.e. 11MB) to store the lists, supposing you duplicate the words every time, and less than 1MB if you only store indices in the lists (I'm not counting various overheads introduced by lists/arrays etc.)

Comment: but what if the query is `m________a`

Comment: @minseong you query for `m_____`, then retain only those that end with `a`

Comment: that's not very fast though is it?